# convert System.Type to a T Parameter

Tags: c#, json, generics, types

I have the `System.Type` of an object, and I want to use it as a parameter to a generic function: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()`

Of course `JsonConvert.DesierializeObject<theType>()` does not work.. I seem to need the name of the class but I am not sure how to get it from the type.

Is there a way to convert the type back into a T so I can call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using json.net? `JsonConvert` has another method

```
 public static object DeserializeObject(string value, Type type);
```

you can use this one,like

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ some json }", theType);
```

Comment: I was just writing up the exact same question and this came up. what a good find. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I guess that DeserializeObject is a static method? Try to use reflection:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(JsonConverter).GetMethod("DeserializeObject", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var genericArguments = new Type[] { theType };
var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments );
var result = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
```

And if `DeserializeObject` tooks some parameters then pass them in the second parameter of `Invoke` method in the last line...

Comment: Charlie answered the specific question for JSonConvert, but this answer is more general